# BizTalk Server Development - Doing it the Biztalk way

Tags: architecture, biztalk

I recently had an integration project with a very short timeline.  It's a requirement that we use Biztalk where all the integration related processes are centralized.

My project requires that I use a job queue pattern where an order coming from the procurement system may result into multiple tasks which must be executed in order.  This becomes more complex as more tasks are created for that order on certain events later in time.

Writing a framework for this which can be reusable, easy to maintain, and pluggable for later use with new customers, target system, and transactions can't be handled in BizTalk.   I instead opted for pure C# + EF4.1 approach, where the job creation and execution is initiated from Biztalk.

Basically, we have reduced BizTalk to take the role of Windows Service.

Is this bad design?  Is this a poor approach?   My heart says it is, but with the constraints I'm faced with this is the best approach available.

However, ultimately, we are building software solutions to address problems.  Even if it means not following the norm.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts are - firstly, if you're forced to use a tool which is unsuited to the job at hand for no other reason than to fulfill some idiotic policy, then relegating it to some token function within the overall architecture is acceptable.

However, BizTalk is a tool which which has a *very specific set of skills*. For example, high volume messaging, very fast xslt transforms, and easy-to-configure routing and monitoring. If you need any of these features within your system, you could do worse than utilize BizTalk for them.

Comment: We do use BizTalk the way it's meant to be used.  I just need to use BizTalk for this particular project so we have all applications centralized in a single admin console.  Anyway, we just went live last week and everything's gone well.   I could've designed the whole thing utilizing BizTalk but it would've taken more time and wouldn't be as performant as opposed to a pure c# implementation.

Comment: Congrats for the successful release!